# Using Struts tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, struts

We have some widgets developed using Dojo and Javascript. The dojo code invokes some application services using io script mechanism to overcome cross browser issues. Currently the action for the io script is hard coded as follows.

var host="myhost.com";
var url = "http://"+host+"/context/service";

Every time we need to create WAR, we have to change host details. Is there a way in JS we can configure this ie., some thing like reading it from properties.

I found this s:url struts tag. I assume we can use this tag inside javascript code in a JSP. Can i use it in plain JS out side of JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you have your container set up to process `*.js` files as JSP files.

IMO this is a bit brittle.

You can also do things like hide data in the DOM via hidden elements or `<script>` tags with reasonable `type` attributes (e.g., not `"text/javascript"`, the default).

You can also put the data into JavaScript variables in the JSP and access them from external JS files.